# ReportLab pdf with only black and white colours (grey scale)?

Tags: reportlab

Is it possible it generate pdf document with only black and white colours (grey scale) in reportLab python?

I dont want other other colours to appear in the document.

https://www.reportlab.com/software/opensource/

Answer (score 0):

Of course. Just don't set anything to a color other than black or white. There's literally nothing else to it. Just don't draw in color.